# Finiteness of Lusternik-Shnirelman category

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Are there conditions on a topological space $X$ under which its Lusternik-Shnirelman category is countable (or even finite)?

"Countable Lusternik-Shnirelman category" means that $X$ can be covered by countable many sets, each of them is contractible in $X$. (And "finite L-S category" means of course it's covered by finitely many such sets.)

I'm interested in topological spaces which are not necessarily CW-complexes.

Comment: if $X$ is compact is a natural one

Comment: Even that does not seem so obvious. Why should any point have any contractible neighborhood?

Comment: Well, you should start by restricting to locally contractible spaces anyway, I think. If not, $\{1,1/2,\dots, 0\}$ is a compact non-locally-contractible space.

Comment: But on the other hand a space $X$ does not have to be locally contractible to have for each point a neighborhood that is contractible in $X$. Think of a contractible, but not locally contractible space.